# Strange behavior of `tasks` items inside `tcolorbox` box

Tags: tcolorbox, tasks

I am drawing a fancy box around theorem environment using `tcolorbox` package. The content of the environment contain horizontal enumerate and I prefer `tasks` package. The default box setting work perfectly fine with the contents. However, when I reduce the frame line thickness, it turns out to be a problem (please refer to the MWE and screenshots). So what is the matter? Is it a bug of `tcolorbox` package?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
%\tcolorboxenvironment{example}{colframe=red!70!black,colback=magenta!9!white} % this work perfectly but the frame line is too thick.
\tcolorboxenvironment{example}{colframe=red!70!black,colback=magenta!9!white,boxrule=1pt}% adding boxrule=1pt key cause the problem
\begin{document}
    \begin{example}
        Compute determinant of the following matrice:
        \begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](3)
            \task $ \displaystyle A=\begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 2\\
            3 & 4
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task $ \displaystyle B=\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & 2 & 4\\
            6 & 8 & 10\\
            12 & 14 & 16
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task $ \displaystyle |C|=\begin{vmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12}\\
            a_{21} & a_{22}
            \end{vmatrix} $
        \end{tasks}
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `box` values lower than 1pt or greater than 1.2pt place three tasks on same line. `box` values between (included) 1.pt and 1.2pt place third task on lower line.

Comment: @Ignasi: I tried to vary the value of `boxrule` and for the `boxrule=1.1pt` place the three task on one line (TeXlive 2017)! However, 1pt and 1.2 pt place the third task on another line.

Comment: In any case I wanted to point that the problem is not with `box` option or any other option but with specific values assigned to `box`. I think your question is not clear on this point.